# PATH for scheduled tasks

Tags: java, path, cron

On my Linux-driven Synology DS215i, I have a scheduled task that calls a user-defined script that starts a java-class. It runs under root-account.

This is the user-defined script:

```
bash /volume1/homes/admin/java/telegram.sh
```

This is the telegram.sh itself:

```
java SendMessage
```

The output is:

```
/volume1/homes/admin/java/telegram.sh: line 1: java: command not found
```

So I added the java-bin path to crontab (...and rebooted my NAS):

```
PATH=/sbin:/bin:/usr/sbin:/usr/bin:/usr/syno/sbin:/usr/syno/bin:/usr/local/sbin:/usr/local/bin:/var/packages/Java8/target/j2sdk-image/bin
```

Anyway, it didn't help, the output is still the same.

If I run the script from putty command-line the java program is executed correctly...

And ideas?

Comment: Is your scheduled task scheduled via the system's crond or some Java facility?

Comment: It is indeed scheduled via Synology's Task Scheduler...

Comment: This is not actually a programming question. It's more about setting up a task in Synology task manager. Anyway, you may want to ensure that having rebooted your NAS did not remove that setting from your crontab, and further, to make sure that you got the right path. That is, that there is indeed an executable called `java` at `/var/packages/Java8/target/j2sdk-image/bin`.

Comment: It's in the path, yes, and the path still exists after rebooting.
I:m wondering, if the synology's task scheduler uses a "private" path?